# How to change background color of GtkTextView?

Tags: gtk

How to change background color of GtkTextView? I tried with normal widget set bg functionality but gtk is just changing border color of GtkText View.

Plus can some some please explain me with simple example, that how to change Text Color/Font/Text Size in GtkTextView (Whole text in GtkTextView)?

I fond some examples but they are not working..

Thnaks,
PP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
gtk_widget_modify_base()
```

http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-modify-base

Comment: This is an obsolete answer. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

> **`gtk_widget_override_background_color()`**

This the GTK 3.x+ way (until GTK 3.16). From

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-modify-base

"`gtk_widget_modify_base` has been deprecated since version 3.0 and should not be used in newly-written code. Use `gtk_widget_override_background_color()` instead"

UPDATE: thegtknerd notes that this method too is now deprecated and it has been since 3.16.

Comment: Your link states that it is deprecated too.

Answer (score 1):

As of gtk3, I believe the proper way to do that is through CSS. Register a gtk style sheet [though GtkCssProvider](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html), then you can write this CSS:

```css
textview text {
  background-color: @theme_bg_color;
}
```

We can see the relevant CSS nodes in the documentation for GtkTextView. In this case I put `@theme_bg_color` which is [an adwaita CSS variable](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/gtk-3-22/gtk/theme/Adwaita/_colors-public.scss), but you can as well put anything that goes in a usual CSS file, like `red` or `#ff0000`.